# Creating of specific process tree

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to create a process tree as on [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua7K1.png). Down below is my code, that i wrote. It works properly but only a half. The output of my code is on the [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G78eU.png). The problem is, that i don't know, how to make the last generation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() {
    int i;
    int j;

    pid_t ppid;
    pid_t cpid;
    ppid = getpid();
    printf("I'm the parent, my PID is: %d\n", ppid);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ppid = fork();
        if (ppid == 0) {
            printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                ppid = fork();
                if (ppid == 0) {
                    printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                    sleep(60);
                    printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            sleep(60);
            printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }   
    }

    sleep(1);
    printf("I'm process %d. Waiting for one of my children to complete", getpid());
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Eltern: I'm done\n");
    printf("... and bye. \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you just need to add a `fork` in the inner most if-statement.

```
            if (ppid == 0) {
                printf("Hello, my PID is: %d, my parent's PID is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

                // Add one more fork here

                sleep(60);
                printf("I'm process %d and I'm done\n", getpid());
                exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: Thx. Maybe you could help on more time. How can i make, that each parent process is waiting for his child process to complete? In my code only the first generation parent waits for his children.

Comment: Have tries `wait` or `waitpid` just before all `exit`?

Comment: jep. wait(null). Just came to it by myself. Thx :)